# What is the geometric interpretation of $ \frac{1}{2}||a||^2\leq \langle a,b\rangle $?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometric-interpretation

Give $a, b$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. What is the geometric interpretation of the following?

$$ \frac{1}{2}\|a\|^2 \leq \langle a,b\rangle $$

In other words, what criteria should $a$ and $b$ have to satisfy the above inequality?

If possible, please provide 2D interpretation when $n=2$.

Comment: @ Thomas: that could be one of the criteria (non negativeness of the right hand side) for $a,b$ to have the in equality. As you pointed out, the angle between $a, b$ should be cute. Also, exclude the case which makes them orthogonal.

Comment: I had misunderstood the question. So, if you fix a, that condition on b says that the projection of b on a must be larger than a fixed number. Therefore b belongs in 2D to a semiplane with a boindary orthogonal to a. Further the boundary of the semiplane passes through a/2, which is the limiting case making the inequality an identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a$ is $0$, then any $b$ will satisfy the inequality.

If $a$ is different from $0$, then it is a bit more interesting. We can draw a line segment from $0$ to $a$ and perpendicularly bisect it like so:

[image]

This line divides the plane into two regions. All the vectors $b$ which are on the same side as $a$ (the shaded region) will satisfy the inequality, and the others won’t.

I will leave it up to you to formalize this argument for $\mathbf{R}^n$ in terms of orthogonal subspaces, but this picture can serve as a motivation.

Comment: Also n=3 can be visualized like that :)

Comment: @Thomas the visualization could even work for $\mathbf{R}^1$ where the bisector is just the number $a/2$, and the region is all the numbers which are on the same side as $a$.

Answer (score 4):

There's an equivalent interpretation in terms of distances.

The condition $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\|a\|^2 \leq \langle a,b\rangle$ is equivalent to $\|a\|^2 - 2\langle a,b\rangle \leq 0$. Observe that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|a-b\|^2 &= \langle a - b, a - b\rangle \\
 &= \langle a,a \rangle - 2\langle a,b\rangle + \langle b, b\rangle \\
&= \|a\|^2 - 2\langle a,b \rangle + \|b\|^2
\end{aligned}$$
Therefore $\|a\|^2 - 2 \langle a,b \rangle \leq 0$ if and only if $\|a-b\|^2 \leq \|b\|^2$, if and only if $\|a-b\| \leq \|b\|$.

So, $a$ and $b$ satisfy the condition if and only if $b$ is closer to $a$ than it is to the origin. This is an equivalent characterization to the one given in the answer by @shoteyes.